# How to update model in template Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have function in controller:

```
$scope.get = function (id) {

                appService._filter({user: id, tab : $scope.selectedTab}).then(function (response) {

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            $scope.app = [];
                            $scope.app = response.app;
                        });
                    }, 100);


                });
            };
```

I get response inside function and try do refresh model `$scope.app`, but this variable is not changed in template. I tried some solution. How I can refresh `$scope.app`?

My tempate is:

```
<div class="user-item item" ng-repeat="(key, itm) in filtered = (app | filter:searchInside | orderObjectBy:'Id':true | groupBy: 'date_title') track by $index">
   <div ng-repeat="item in itm" class="item-block"></div>
</div>
```

My `filter` is from service:

```
filter: function (_filter) {
     filter = _filter;
     return this.get(filter);
},

get: function (paramObj) {
                var appPromise = $q.defer();
                filter = (paramObj != null) ? paramObj : filter;

                $http({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "/app/get",
                    data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(filter),
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                })
                    .success(function (data) {
                        return appPromise.resolve(data);
                    })
                    .error(function (error) {
                        return appPromise.reject(error);
                    });

                return appPromise.promise;
            },
```

Comment: What does your template look like? Also, why are you using `setTimeout`?

Comment: You can see my template in question, also setTimout is not reason of problem

Comment: Someone can help me?